# Php download prompt opened but no contents are downloading

Tags: php, download

I have a file(mp3 speech files) download functionality in my website. When users are trying to download the file, for some users it is working fine. For others it just opened the browser download window and it remains without downloading any content. it is showing 0% even after half an hour. can anyone suggest a solution.

The site is developed in PHP. The users are from USA. Will this happen due to any firewall?

below is the code for downloading the file

```
header("Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: public");

header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $originalFileName . '"');
header('Content-Length: '.$fileSize);

//open the file
$fp = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
//seek to start of missing part
fseek($fp, $seek_start);

//start buffered download
while(!feof($fp))
{
    //reset time limit for big files
    set_time_limit(0);
    print(fread($fp, 1024*8));
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    session_write_close();
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Nobody has any clue what's going on if you don't post any code.

Comment: Without a code sample, I'd say no, no one can suggest a solution :/ How are you sending the download via PHP?

Answer (score -1):

You can write `session_write_close()` outside of the `while` loop.

I think if you are closing session again and again then it will not work.

Comment: no it is not working.... I have already tried it by removing the  session_write_close() function

Comment: well also flush it at last not in between